# How to detect URLs blocked by the ISP/government from JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, security, privacy, connectivity, internet-connection

What are some reasonable approaches in client-side JS to detect whether a given URL is blocked for the user on whose browser the code is running?  Is there a lib or other project that does this for some types of blocks?

In Russia, for example, https://linkedin.com redirects to http://denypage.ru/ due to being on the government's blacklist.  But other governments:
- simply throttle, which is harder to detect
- block the URLs used by messenger apps
- force platforms to block specific accounts
...

See also: Tor's [OONI project](https://ooni.torproject.org/), Twitter's [policy on so-called *Country Withheld Content™*](https://support.twitter.com/articles/20169222), TurkeyBlocks.org's [methodology](https://turkeyblocks.org/methodology/)

Comment: You typically can't detect *why* something is unavailable, only that it is. A government firewall set to deny traffic will look much like a local firewall and even a firewall dropping traffic might look like an unstable connection.

Comment: Sure, isn't expected to be perfect, just to catch the obvious cases and, in aggregate, a few more.